# Name of theorem in ODE theory

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry

Can anyone tell me what the name of the following theorem from ODE theory is? Also, to clarify, is the gradient on the RHS with respect to $X$?

I found it [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/284718):

> Let $\mathbf V \colon [0,T] \times \mathbb R^d \to \mathbb R^d$ (for $T>0$) be a given, bounded smooth vector field and let $\mathbf X=\mathbf X(t,x)$ be its *flow*, i.e. the unique solution to the initial-value problem
> \begin{equation}
> \begin{cases}
> \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \mathbf X(t,x) = \mathbf V(t,\mathbf X(t,x)) & \text{ in } (0,T) \times \mathbb R^d \\
> \mathbf X(0,x) = x \quad \text{ for all } x \in \mathbb R^d.    
> \end{cases}
> \end{equation}  A well-known result in standard ODE's theory says that
> $$\tag{1}
> \nabla_x \mathbf X(t,x) = \exp\bigg( \int_0^t \nabla \mathbf V(s,\mathbf X(s,x))\,ds\bigg).   
> $$

Comment: Are you sure that the claim is completely reproduced? It resembles the result for determinants, if $\dot M=AM$, then $\frac{d}{dt}\det(M)={\rm tr}(A)\det(M)$ which gives the exponential formula for $\det(M)$ by standard separation. The claimed equation would then describe the evolution of an infinitesimal volume under the ODE, showing that it only depends on the divergence of the vector field.

Comment: I am not entirely sure. I think the result you are citing (the evolution of an infinitesimal volume under the ODE only depends on the divergence of the vector field) is known as Liouville's theorem (found in page 99 of Introduction to Applied Nonlinear Dynamical Systems and Chaos by Stephen Wiggins · 2003)